# Handling Session timeout in asp.net so all info. is aviable before create/update record

Tags: asp.net

I'm having problem with some data missing in the record. I've a ASP.net web app that take some information from the user then create a record on the database. It's your typical CRUD app but I've noticed lately that some record are missing couple fields. Where they are null value. I think it might have been an Session issue.

What's the best way to handle session time out in a typical CRUD app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I there is opportunity to update data in your application without being authorized is a great security issue. I think the better way is restrict unauthorized access can handle such situation in future.
To clean up user related data(when user session was ended) you can use Session_End event in Global.asax.